# PHP array sum up session value not adding item after removing comma

Tags: php, arrays, addition

I am trying to add up the sum of an array of prices with the below code:

```
 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
    $sum += str_replace(",", "", $item['price']);
    echo $sum;                   
}
```

`$item['price']` in above is `10,000 and 5,000` and I used `str_replace` to remove the comma and sum the values up with `+=` but instead of `echo $sum` to give `15000` it is giving `1000015000` and I'm not sure where I got it wrong.

Comment: Multiplying $item by 1 will ensure it is read as a number.

Comment: using [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) would also be cleaner

Comment: The problem isn't your values or your `+=`. The problem is that you're echoing the sum inside the foreach, which means that you first echo 10000 and then 15000 after each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. The problem isn't your values or your `+=`. The problem is that you're echoing the sum inside the foreach, which means that you first add 10000, which you echo. Then add 5000, which will give you 15000, which you then echo after the first 10000 you've already echoed.

Just put the echo *after* the foreach and you're set.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
    $sum += str_replace(",", "", $item['price']);
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
    $sum += intval(str_replace(",", "", $item['price']));                
 }
 echo $sum;
```